# Android ListView divider different for every second row

Tags: android, xamarin, android-view

So I have a divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
</shape>
```

My View looks like this :

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Mvx.MvxListView
            android:id="@+id/suppliersListView"
            android:divider="@drawable/divider"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start" 
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_supplier"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ReceptionSuppliersList; ItemClick ReceptionBasicInformationSelectCommand"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

in @layout/item_supplier i have no red styling attributes.

[image]

So when I run the view it shows like this, my 2nd,4th etc... line are way more highlighted then the line between 1st and 2nd element.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Issue on emulator or real device

Comment: @dit simulator for now.

Comment: check in real device then no issue found

Comment: this is normal behavior for an emulator.

Comment: @dit post it as an aswer so i can accept it. It was indeed a emulator behavior, any ideas why it is like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typically behaviour for an emulator. Some pixels get lost while painting of tiny objects like lines or dots.

Start your app on a real device and it should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Add below properties in your `Listview`  And use your prefered color in  `android:divider` And put Transparent Color in `android:cacheColorHint` like below:

```
android:divider="#00000000"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

Comment: it was an issue from the emulator, i've tested on device and it shows the same thickness for all lines.

Comment: fadingEdge and cacheColorHint  highlighting views while scrolling or in view in  focus .